# Issue with .NullString property displaying "-" as 0 in output

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing some VBA code, a section of it is supposed to fill in the PivotTable cells that are Null with the character "-".

Unfortunately using "-" just fills the table with 0 instead; I would like the Null Values to display a dash "-".

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ThePivotTable")
 .NullString = "-"
 .DisplayNullString = True
End With
```

But oddly works for anything else 
ie "'-" displays '- as intended, "NA" displays as NA as intended

Comment: Try the en dash, `chrw$(&h2013)`.

Comment: @GSerg en-dash works. However, for some reason company formatting wants hypens instead of en-dash. 

Any ideas as to why the hypen isn't working as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it might be connected to your Number Format. Try adding one more line to your code:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ThePivotTable")
    .NullString = "-"
    .DisplayNullString = True
    .DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00;-#,##0.00;-"
End With
```

Comment: This displays minus instead of zeros. So if you have a genuine zero (as opposed to a blank), it will display a minus too. I thought the idea was to only display the minus for blank cells. The minus you then see in the table comes from the format string, not from NullString.

Comment: This is correct, I originally had my 
```numberformat="#,##0"
```